# Can we use bootstrap library with Struts 1 Java application

Tags: java, twitter-bootstrap, glassfish-3, struts-1

I am trying to redesign the UI for our Struts 1.x Java application. Currently we are using Jquery UI but to give the new look and feel to the application I want to use bootstrap for the buttons we use. Can anybody let me know if its possible to use Bootstrap with Struts 1.X

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Struts is framework on top of JSP/Servlets layer, its responsibility starts from receiving of HTTP request and ends with delivering HTML content to client.

JQuery UI and Boostrap are **client side** technologies, based on technologies provided by Browser (CSS for styles, Javascript for rich experience). You can choose any of them of event mix them in one project (don't recommend to do

So yes, you definitely can use Bootstrap with Struts 1.X or any other Web Framework.